plugin issue in jenkins2.173.2
I have to install a plugin Usage Plugin in jenkins 2.173.2.this plugin was released about a month ago. According to its documentation, it requires Jenkins version 2.375.4 or higher. My Jenkins instance is currently running version 2.173.2.
Is there any way to confirm whether this plugin will not support Jenkins version 2.173.2? Additionally, what alternative methods can I use to determine if this plugin is being utilized by any jobs in my Jenkins instance given the version compatibility constraints?"
i want to use this plugin to know how many plugins are being used by the jobs i have some depricated plugins i want to know those are used by any jobs or can i remove if they are not in use
